# Element position is changing after navigation

Tags: angular, angular-material, dialog, nrwl-nx

I have this weird issue with positioning of a modal dialog (MatDialog). It works on the first try, but after I navigate to another page and go back, the position is calculated outside of the viewport, with height being aroung 1000 pixels off.

Search input on the menu bar:

```html
<div class="h-full w-full flex justify-end" *transloco="let t">
  <div #searchElem class="px-3 leading-none h-full w-80 relative flex justify-start justify-self-end items-top border-l" >
    <!-- search input -->
  </div>
</div>
```

This is how I calculate the position for the mat dialog:

```typescript
@ViewChild('searchElem') set sectionToolbar(el: ElementRef) {
  this.calculateDialogPosition(el);
}

private calculateDialogPosition(elem: ElementRef): void {
  if (elem) {
    const native = elem.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    const { bottom, left } = native.getBoundingClientRect();

    this.dialogPos = { left: `${left}px`, top: `${bottom}px` };
    console.log('POS:', this.dialogPos);
  }
}

// Position when navigating to the page for the first time:
// POS: Object { left: "320px", top: "157px" }
// Any following navigation leads to the positions like this:
// POS: Object { left: "320px", top: "1326.9999694824219px" }
```

It looks like that when `@ViewChild` gets the `ElementRef`; the actual element is offset from the screen and I get the incorrect position. What's the workaround for this? Preferably something without having to use some service.

Just a note: the application has Micro Frontend architecture, put together with Nx/Webpack. But the issue occurs also when navigating withing the module.